# Setting the value in NSDictionary from JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, nsdictionary

I have parsed the JSON data, now while setting the JSON to my `NSDictionary` there might be certain keys in the JSON that might not be present. I want to check if the key is present in the JSON parsed to me and if not, set blank field as value to the key in the `NSDictionary' object.

```
jsonData = ["id": ((json["idnumber"]) as? String!)!,
          "Name": ((json["name"]) as? String!)!,
   "Roll Number": ((json["rollnumber"]) as? String!)!,
         "Class": ((json["class"]) as? String!)!,
         "Marks": ((json["marks"]) as? String!)!,
        "Gender": ((json["gender"]) as? String!)!]
```

So in the above case, the marks field may or may not be present in the JSON. I want to check this and assign respective value to the corresponding key in `jsonData`.

I tried using "??", but it takes lot of compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if let` or `guard` for conditional optional wrapping for that like this.

```
var jsonData = [String : String]
if let num = json["idnumber"]) as? String {
    jsonData["id"] = num
}
else {
    jsonData["id"] = num
}
```

and so on for others.

**Edit:** You can also try like this.

```
var id = name = rollNum = class = ""
if let num = json["idnumber"]) as? String {
    id = num
}
if let sname = json["name"]) as? String {
    name = sname
}
...
```

Then at last create `Dictionary`

```
var jsonData = ["id": id, "name": name, ...]
```

Comment: Works good. But is there an alternative for this so as to optimise the code. Consider i have 35 to 40 of such fields then for each field i need to write these 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value if present otherwise blank string (""). This will prevent crash. Try below code:-

```
        let idValue = dictionary["idnumber"] as? String ?? ""
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let rollNumber = dictionary["rollnumber"] as? String ?? ""
        let className = dictionary["class"] as? String ?? ""
        let marks = dictionary["marks"] as? String ?? ""
        let gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String ?? ""

        let jsonDic : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        jsonDic.setObject(idValue, forKey: "id")
        jsonDic.setObject(name, forKey: "name")
        jsonDic.setObject(className, forKey: "class")
        jsonDic.setObject(rollNumber, forKey: "rollNumber")
        jsonDic.setObject(marks, forKey: "marks")
        jsonDic.setObject(gender, forKey: "gender")
```

Comment: i tried the solution given by you. The problem with "??" is that it takes lot of compilation time. I have more than 30 fields. Even if you use 10 of "??" the project doesn't compile.

Comment: The presence and number of "??" operators in your code should not affect the compilation time significantly and having many of them will not prevent your code compiling.  It sounds like you may have a problem in your Xcode set up.  What version are you using?

Comment: i tried     jsonData = ["id": ((json["idnumber"]) as? String!)! ?? " ",
          "Name": ((json["name"]) as? String!)! ?? " "]          Xcode7.3 throws this error : Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions